# Choice certain keys from Riak

Tags: erlang, riak

I started to learn working with Riak and faced with problem of getting the keys.

Function `list_keys` from `riak-erlang-client` allows to get all keys from some bucket.

But sometimes it's necessary to get just a part of key (in particular, all keys are added in a period of time). How can I do this?

Comment: `list_keys/2` and `list_keys/3` didn't accept other parameter than timeout. If you want to fetch keys that were added in date range, consider using either [secondary index](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/2i/) or [riak search](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/search/), depending on your needs (if you need deep pagination, then go with 2i, otherwise riak search are preferable for most of query operation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to get a partial list of keys you will need to do one of the following:

- Use secondary indexes (2i) and range queries (http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/references/http/secondary-indexes/)
- Filter using MapReduce (http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/keyfilters/)
- Use Riak Search 2.0 (Solr)

The List Keys function isn't something intended to be used in production so you will need to design around that limitation if your application requires this functionality.